# How do I change the data in a label in Perl Tk?

Tags: perl, tk-toolkit

I'm trying to create a program with Tk that will take the data from an entry, and, at the click of a button, create a label that has that data.

Below is the code I've been debugging.  In the process of debugging, I have tried tb]geh following:

- using references to `$printItem`
- have the subroutine connected to `-command` go to a subroutine
- combining the above in various ways

```perl
use Tk; use strict; use warnings;

$mw = MainWindow -> new;

my $printItem = $mw -> Entry(-width = 20); $printItem -> pack;

$mw -> Button(-text => "Write.", -command => sub{ $mw -> Label(-text => "$printItem") -> pack} -> pack;

MainLoop;
```

When I click the button, all that the label shows is `Tk::Entry=HASH([seemingly random hexadecimal number here])`.  This is obviously not what I want, and I'd like to know how I can get the effect I desire.

Comment: I'd say use `Label(-text => $printItem->get)`, but that's a guess and I can't try it because you haven't provided a [mcve].

Comment: Does what I have not count?  Also, your solution worked.  If you put it as answer, I can confirm it.

Comment: No, it doesn't even compile: `Global symbol "$mw" requires explicit package name (did you forget to declare "my $mw"?) at try.pl line 3.` Also, `-width = 20` needs to be `-width => 20`. And you're missing a `)` somewhere.

Comment: Ah.  You're right.  I can fix it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Tk::Entry=HASH(0xdeadbeef)` is how Perl stringifies objects. And indeed, your `$printItem` variable stores an object of class `Tk::Entry`:

```
my $printItem = $mw -> Entry(-width = 20);
```

To get the string from a [Tk::Entry](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/Tk/pod/Entry.pod) widget, you can use its [`get` method](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/Tk/pod/Entry.pod#$entry-%3Eget):

```
... -command => sub { $mw->Label(-text => $printItem->get)->pack } ...
```

Complete working example:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Tk;

my $mw = MainWindow->new;

my $printItem = $mw->Entry(-width => 20); $printItem->pack;

$mw->Button(-text => "Write.", -command => sub { $mw->Label(-text => $printItem->get)->pack })->pack;

MainLoop;
```