# Packing an array causes "Can't locate method" error in perl

Tags: perl, tk-toolkit

I am trying to create a basic GUIed backup system in perl using Tk and Archive::Tar.  Nothing complicated, just a frontend for making .tar.bz2 files.  So, one of the arguments for an Archive::Tar command is an array.  To determine what is to be put in that array, I need to recieve information from an entry box, which I included with Tk.  However, the program doesn't compile, and produces a "Can't locate method" error at the line where the entry is packed.

The following is an example (make sure the packages are installed!):

```perl
use strict; use warnings;

use Tk;

my $mw = MainWindow -> new;

@filelist = $mw -> Entry( -width = 30 );
@filelist -> pack;
```

How can I modify this code to create the desired effect?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I change the data in a label in Perl Tk?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56760432/how-do-i-change-the-data-in-a-label-in-perl-tk)

Comment: Nope.  That was me trying to get a label to appear at the push of a button.  This time, I'm trying to store entry data in an array.

Comment: The basic issue is the same: You're treating a `Tk::Entry` widget as if it were the data the user entered. In either case you would need to call the `get` method to get the user input.

Comment: This comment from the other question also applies: *No, it doesn't even compile: `Global symbol "$mw" requires explicit package name (did you forget to declare "my $mw"?) at try.pl line 3.`*

Comment: Ooops.  I can fix it.

Answer (score 2):

The `Entry` method returns a single object. You can find its documentation [here](http://p3rl.org/Tk::Entry).

`@filelist` is an array. You can't call methods on arrays, only on scalars.

The standard way is to use the [Tk::getOpenFile](http://p3rl.org/Tk::getOpenFile) widget:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature qw{ say };

use Tk;

my $mw = MainWindow->new;
my $button = $mw->Button(
    -text => 'Select Files',
    -command => sub {
        my $files = $mw->getOpenFile(-multiple => 1);
        say for @$files;
    },
)->pack;

MainLoop();
```

Comment: This is great, but it won't work for my application.  I need something that con select multiple files or a directory, if at all possible.  I guess what I'm looking for is something that can take the input from the entry and turn it into an array.